# why not changing filtered sort data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, methods

I am Currently Creating Filter Option to Item List. but its not filtering when i select the dropdown options.

Array in App.jsx

```
const cameraShowList=[
    {id:1,model:"Canon",title:"Canon EOS M50 Mark II Mirrorless",price:"LKR 245000",img1:img11,img2:img12,img3:img13,matirial:"EOS M50",wifi:"-",display:"3'",view:"Electronic",sensor:"CMOS",lensor:"-",pixel:"24.1",iso:"Auto, 100 to 25600 (Extended: 100 to 51200)",battery:"1 x LP-E12 Rechargeable Lithium-Ion, 7.2 VDC, 875 mAh"},
    {id:2,model:"canon",title:"Canon 3000D with Canon EF-S",price:"LKR 145000",img1:img21,img2:img22,matirial:"Canon 3000D",wifi:"Yes",display:"2.7'",view:"Eye-level pentamirror",sensor:"CMOS",lensor:"18-55mm lens",pixel:"18",iso:"100-6400",battery:"LP-E10"},
    {id:3,model:"canon",title:"Canon EOS 250D DSLR Camera",price:"LKR 218000",img1:img31,img2:img32,img3:img33,matirial:"EOS 250D",wifi:"Yes",display:"3'",view:"Optical pentamirror",sensor:"CMOS",lensor:"18-55mm lens",pixel:"24.5'",iso:"100-25600",battery:"1 x LP-E10"},
    {id:4,model:"canon",title:"Canon EOS 200D Mark II",price:"LKR 240000",img1:img42,img2:img41,matirial:"EOS 200D",wifi:"Yes",display:"3'",view:"Eye-level pentamirror",sensor:"CMOS",lensor:"18-55mm lens",pixel:"24.5'",iso:"Auto, 100 to 51200",battery:"LP-E17"},
    {id:5,model:"Nikon",title:"Nikon D7500 DSLR Camera",price:"LKR 368000",img1:img53,img2:img52,img3:img53,matirial:"D7500",wifi:"Yes",display:"3.2'",view:"Optical pentamirror",sensor:"CMOS",lensor:"18-140mm lens",pixel:"20.9'",iso:"100-25600",battery:"1 x EN-EL15a"},
    {id:6,model:"Nikon",title:"Nikon D3500 DSLR Camera",price:"LKR 368000",img1:img51,img2:img52,img3:img53,matirial:"D3500",wifi:"Yes",display:"3.2'",view:"Optical pentamirror",sensor:"CMOS",lensor:"18-140mm lens",pixel:"20.9'",iso:"100-25600",battery:"1 x EN-EL15a"},
    {id:7,model:"Nikon",title:"Nikon EOS DSLR Camera",price:"LKR 368000",img1:img52,img2:img51,img3:img53,matirial:"EOS 500",wifi:"Yes",display:"3.2'",view:"Optical pentamirror",sensor:"CMOS",lensor:"18-140mm lens",pixel:"20.9'",iso:"100-25600",battery:"1 x EN-EL15a"},
    {id:8,model:"Nikon",title:"Nikon D1500 DSLR Camera",price:"LKR 368000",img1:img31,img2:img52,img3:img53,matirial:"D1500",wifi:"Yes",display:"3.2'",view:"Optical pentamirror",sensor:"CMOS",lensor:"18-140mm lens",pixel:"20.9'",iso:"100-25600",battery:"1 x EN-EL15a"},
```

]

**CardSection.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Card from './Card'

function CardSection(props) {

    const [sortOption,setSortOption]=useState("")

    const handleSortChange=(e)=>{
        setSortOption(e.target.value);
    }

    const sortedShopList = () => {
        switch (sortOption) {
          case 'lowToHigh':
            return props.shopList.slice().sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
          case 'highToLow':
            return props.shopList.slice().sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);
          default:
            return props.shopList.slice();
        }
      };

  return (
    <div className='mt-[3rem] md:w-auto pt-[5rem] px-6 md:pt-[5%] md:px-[4rem]'>
        <h1 className='text-center font-bold text-[2rem]'>Our Most Exclusive Products</h1>
        <div className='mt-5 flex justify-end items-center gap-3'>
            <h2 className='font-semibold'>Filter</h2>
            <select className='border-2 p-2 rounded-lg' value={sortOption} onChange={handleSortChange}>
                <option value="">Recent</option>
                <option value="lowToHigh">Low to High(Price)</option>
                <option value="highToLow">High to Low(Price)</option>
            </select>
        </div>


        <div className='flex flex-col items-center mt-3 gap-4'>
                   <div className='flex flex-wrap items-center justify-center gap-6'>
                     {sortedShopList().slice(0, 4).map((i) => (
                       <Card id={i.id} name={i.title} price={i.price} img={i.img1} />
                       ))}
                   </div>
                 
                   <div className='flex flex-wrap items-center justify-center gap-6'>
                     {sortedShopList().slice(4, 8).map((i) => (
                       <Card id={i.id} name={i.title} price={i.price} img={i.img1}/>
                     ))}
                   </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default CardSection
```

I used my basic knowlage of react and use test my knowlage about javascript methods. what i do wrong in this code? how i fix this issue?

Comment: Are you asking about *filtering* or about *sorting*?  It's not clear.  Can you create a fully working [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price property in your objects seems to be strings with `LKR` in them. You need to extract the numeric part of the price before comparing them in the sorting function. Make sure the `price` property in your data is converted to a numeric type before sorting.

```
const sortedShopList = () => {
  switch (sortOption) {
    case 'lowToHigh':
      return props.shopList.slice().sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.price.split(' ')[1]) - parseFloat(b.price.split(' ')[1]));
    case 'highToLow':
      return props.shopList.slice().sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b.price.split(' ')[1]) - parseFloat(a.price.split(' ')[1]));
    default:
      return props.shopList.slice();
  }
};
```

Comment: As @Amit's answer indicates the problem is that your `.sort()` is failing because: `"LKR 123" - "LKR 224"` returns `NaN` (not a number).